# Reflection of functions on function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, transformation

is there an efficient way of plotting somehting like this:

[image]

thank you in advance, cheerz

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Iit is possible draw this *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me", which show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from. Finally, on TeX.SX you thank after the fact by up-voting.

Comment: [perhaps related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401584/how-to-reflect-the-graph-of-a-function-along-any-line/401669#401669)

Comment: What do you mean by efficient ? Do the "reflections" have a specific equation (guassian curves ?). You need to be more precise in your request, `pfgplots` and `tikz` offer so much possibilities !

Answer (score 2):

You already asked a very similar question and got a really nice answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398794/reflection-of-lines-rays-on-function). This answer can be used with minor adjustments to create something similar to your scan. (I wrote this merely because I really like the answer you got and wanted to learn some new tricks.)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[->] (-0.5,0)--(6,0) node[below] {$E$};
\path[name path=Vert,draw,->] (-0.5,0)--(-0.5,4) node[left]{$t$};
\draw[thick,name path=Func,draw,domain=0.1:5,smooth,variable=\x,samples=50]
plot ({\x},{1/pow(\x,1/2)});

\foreach \WaveL[count=\i from 0] in {-0.06,-0.12,-0.24,-0.48,-0.48,-0.24,-0.12,-0.06}{
\path[name path=Vert\i] ({1+\i*0.15},0)--({1+\i*0.15},6);
\path[name intersections={of=Func and Vert\i}] node at (intersection-1)(PointA\i){};

\path[name path=Horiz\i] let \p1=(PointA\i) in(\x1,\y1)--(-0.5,\y1) node[inner sep=0] (PointB\i){};
\node (SWav\i) at ($(PointB\i)-(-\WaveL,0)$){} ;
\draw[dotted] (PointA\i)--({1+\i*0.15},\WaveL);
\draw[dotted] (PointA\i)--($(PointB\i)-(-\WaveL,0)$);
\coordinate (Wav\i) at ({1+\i*0.15},\WaveL);
}
\draw[blue,thick] plot[smooth] coordinates {(Wav0)(Wav1)(Wav2)(Wav3)(Wav4)(Wav5)(Wav6)(Wav7)};
\draw[red,thick] plot[smooth] coordinates {(SWav0)(SWav1)(SWav2)(SWav3)(SWav4)(SWav5)(SWav6)(SWav7)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And sorry, I don't know the functions you had in mind (cf. @BambOo's comment), so I just put some that are somewhat reminiscent of your scan.